# How to resolve this new bug/change in behaviour in PHP 8.x in regards to NumberFormatter?

Tags: php, windows, number-formatting, numberformatter, php-8

I thought I was going crazy before I went out of my way to restore PHP 7.4.13 to try it to make sure. It **has** changed in PHP 8.x!

**Code:**

```
$a = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$a->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 8);
$a->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, ''); // It's empty because I want it "minimal" for a table.
var_dump($a->formatCurrency(0.0043, 'BTC'));
```

**Output in PHP 7.4.13:**

```
string(6) "0.0043"
```

**Output in PHP 8.0.1:**

```
string(11) "BTC 0.0043"
```

**Conclusion:**

Something has changed.

**Question:**

How to make PHP 8.0.1 behave like it used to?

**Clarification:**

That is, to make the money sum outputted in a "minimal" manner, with just the number.

**Prediction 1:**

Somebody might respond something like: "Just output the number manually for these cases!"

To this, I respond: It has to be the number formatter in currency mode. There are wild differences between locales/languages in how money sums are to be formatted. I need to use this and tell it to forgo the symbol.

**Prediction 2:**

Somebody might respond something like: "Just str_replace/preg_replace out the symbol! Easy!"

To this, I respond: Not all locales/languages use the same format. It's a whole science of numerous different formats, impossible to account for with a simple string replacement.

I want to do this right, which is what I thought I had. Until just now, when PHP 8 has decided to change this around. I'm not sure if it's a bug or what.

**Research:**

I cannot find any mention whatsoever of PHP 8 here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

Comment: WFM: https://3v4l.org/6Bj0B

Comment: Report it as a bug to the PHP support

Comment: I even went to the trouble of pulling down the 8.0.1 docker image and adding intl to it, and it still WFM. Is the intl extension actually installed and loaded, or are you using some sort of nonstandard shim for NumberFormatter?

Comment: Well, no. I used the exact example code as I showed to you. This is bizarre. I even tried it again right now, in a "stand-alone" PHP CLI script: `string(11) "BTC 0.0043"`

Comment: Could it possibly have something to do with me running it on Windows? Could there be a difference between the Windows and "Other"/Linux version of PHP in this regard?

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig I found filing a bug to be a massive PITA last time. I may end up having to, but I frankly don't have the energy. The fact that the issue appeared at all makes me feel genuinely worried and sad. It feels like I cannot trust anything to just work and especially continue to work as new versions of the "engine" are released. I'm not a fan of PHP 8 so far.

Comment: It's a long shot, but I notice that most lines of the example have `\NumberFormatter`, but `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL` has no leading backslash. Is it possible you somehow have another class with that name in a different namespace, with the constant defined differently? The other possibility is that while upgrading to PHP 8, you've also changed the version of some system library that this function depends on, and the bug is there - perhaps compare the `intl` sections of the `phpinfo()` output for any clues?

Comment: @IMSoP Well spotted, and I corrected it. However, it was sadly not the issue. Same thing happens with it. I did file this as a bug, BTW, and the one person who responded (so far) also said that he thinks it's ICU's fault. But I don't understand how that can be or what it means in practice, since I just have PHP installed -- no separate ICU or anything: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80611